# Do I need to filter/sanitize/validate GET variables used for filtering of entities

Tags: php, security, get

I'm building a form of catalog that have a form of "filtering" of the entities displayed on the page, not that far of from how a regular web shop is usually working with filtering of categories, price or any other attributes the entities possesses.

With that in mind... Do I, or should care about filtering/sanitizing/validating the incoming GET variables? I'm using a CMS that'll handle (or at least should) and make sure nothing nasty gets into the database.

For example, should I care the users may change the "?fromPrice=1000&toPrice=2000" into something invalid like ?fromPrice=xyz&toPrice=2000".

I've been originally tasked with creating a form of system for this, that'll validate the values and fallback to default values, but I'm struggling to see the point in doing this.

Are there any security points, exception-preventions or whatever, that doing this could bring, or is this just a waste-of-time?

Comment: The short answer is yes IMO. Using your example if the prices should be numeric then checking to make sure that they are in fact numbers and not xyz would be a wise thing to do. The same applies to any other things that may be passed that are expected to be of a certain type.

Comment: I agree with you for the semantics of things, but is there any "actual" reasoning behind doing so, more than just opinion-based?

Comment: Any input from a user, via the URL or a form, should be checked and validated before doing anything with it. That isn't opinion, it's fact. Anything that may be changed by the user should be consider tainted/bad/evil until/unless proven otherwise by validation.

Comment: > Three of the top five most common website attacks – SQL injection, cross-site scripting (XSS), and remote file inclusion (RFI) – share a root cause in common: input sanitization. Or to be more accurate, a lack thereof.https://www.esecurityplanet.com/browser-security/prevent-web-attacks-using-input-sanitization.html

Answer (score 0):

The official solution would be to use php's sanitization: 
http://php.net/manual/ro/filter.filters.sanitize.php

However if it's just from/to price you should just check if they're numbers larger than zero. That should do it for your example, and load defaults if the validation fails.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php for reference

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the question was not really about how-to, but if.